# Make [gpu-programming] a synonym of [gpu]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

The tag wiki for [gpu-programming](/questions/tagged/gpu-programming) is

> See the tag entry for "gpu".

This looks like a pretty clear indication they should be synonyms.

Comment: I even wonder if either of those is really necessary. If it's about graphics, there are more specific tags one could think of than gpu or even gpu-programming. And for other applications there is already [gpgpu] or the various api-specific tags.

Comment: I'd prefer the other way around. But @Bart makes a very good point.